# AS3 slow webcam with 1080p on i3 laptop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, webcam, lag

I made an AIR application that uses the logitech c920 webcam for image capturing. The camera can display and record 720p and 1080p perfectly when I'm using the Logitech software. But when I use 720p in my AIR app there is obvious lag. Still useable, but annoying. 1080p is unacceptable in terms of lag. All this is on an i3 laptop. On my i7 desktop there is much less lag and I can do 1080p, but it's still not nearly as good as when I'm using the Logitech software.

The other odd thing is my older camera, the Logitech 9000 doesn't seem to work properly anymore in Flash or Air. The lag times are several seconds.

My questions are: (1) Do the logitech drivers use GPU acceleration to make the webcams work lightning fast even on a slow i3 computer while Flash cannot?
(2) Why does the older camera give such crumby performance now whether on the i3 or i7? Did Flash change how it handles cameras or something? 
(3) Will the Flash Player be updated to allow GPU acceleration for webcams?

Comment: Is 1080p necessary? And is the video itself laggy or is it the capturing of BitmapData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple truth is that Flash's performance is not good enough for realtime video applications.

Maybe lag would be better if you could [attach your webcam](http://inflagrantedelicto.memoryspiral.com/2012/11/as3-quickie-attach-a-camera-to-stagevideo/) to `StageVideo` (GPU decoding) instead of using the old `Video` class. Or you could simply lower the resolution...

If you want to develop realtime video applications you should take a look at [Cinder](http://libcinder.org/), or [OpenFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/) instead. Both use C++ and performance is amazing. I have personally done projects involving 4k video on multiple monitors with Cinder.

Another option would be using [Max MSP](http://cycling74.com/products/max/), much more powerful than Flash in terms of video performance, and you program visually using nodes and boxes.

Comment: Wow, Cinder does look good. Problem is I don't know C++. Also with StageVideo I can't use bitmapdata to capture images so that won't work for me. Sounds like I deal with the decreased performance in Flash and wait for updates or I remake my entire application in C++. You answered my basic question however and that is the old Video class in flash has it's limitations for high resolution webcam work. Bummer.

Comment: Yes, C++ is the way to go for intensive performance, I found myself in your same situation a few years back and I had to learn C++. I'm going to edit my answer with another option for you. If you find the answer useful please accept it.